# Move Shared mailbox emails older than to specific folder

Tags: outlook, office365

We have a shared mailbox, and I would like to move all emails in that mailbox older than one day to a specific folder.

I did bit of hunt and found that we can do autoarchive, but I don't want to archive those emails. Is there any way to do it?

PS. We currently use Office 365..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoArchive](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-move-or-delete-older-items-with-AutoArchive-e5046b1f-7aa3-4b7b-8828-d3c9bfd8d8f9) is the only option in Office 365 if you want to move your emails to any specific folder which are older than one day.

There is another option which works with specific time span like before 15th Feb etc.. So it won't work in your scenario.

Another best thing to do is configure the shared mailbox directly in Outlook. This will allow you to work with rules, categories and other features just like you would with your own mailbox.

Hope this will help you!